# Colorful shell for Haskell on Windows?

Tags: windows, haskell, console, syntax-highlighting

I'm learning about haskell from [this](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out) tutorial site. As you can see, the console in the pictures have colors, to make writing easier, and more readable. Is there any way to make the ghci colorful on windows.

I ask this because IDLE, has color, when working with Python, which makes it a lot easier to work with.

Comment: I found [this](https://github.com/rhysd/ghci-color) for *nix. It's just a simple script that pipes GHCi output through `sed`, but it doesn't look like it should be too difficult to port to Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[WinGHCi](http://code.google.com/p/winghci/) (included with the Haskell Platform on Windows) supports coloured output in a limited form:

[image: WinGHCi]

I suggest using a real editor for anything more complex than a one-liner.

Comment: Is there any way to add some auto-complete?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac On Linux, ghci has autocomplete by default: http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/223 This should be also supported by WinGHCi.

Comment: I get autocomplete in cmd but not in WinGHCi

Comment: @GamesBrainiac Please [file a bug report](http://code.google.com/p/winghci/issues/entry).

Comment: I've filed a bug report myself: http://code.google.com/p/winghci/issues/detail?id=5